# Firebase Login Persistence Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase to handle my user register and login for my app. But if I log in, and then close my app entirely - the user is forced to re-log in. I'd like to keep the user logged in unless they click "Log out"

My login code is this:

```
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in
            if let firebaseError = error {
                print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            self.presentTabBar()
        })
    }
}
```

How do I keep this user logged in unless specifically told to logout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a handy full example for 2020:

Anywhere in your iOS+Firebase app, you can simply say:

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
    return print("no current user!")
}
```

Thus, on the launch screen of your app, simply:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return print("no current user, hence AuthUI flow...")
            basicAuthUIFlow()
        }
        print("User .. \(Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName)")
        continueWhenUserPresent()
    }
```

It's that easy. So then as usual ...

```
    private func basicAuthUIFlow() {
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        authUI?.delegate = self
        let pp: [FUIAuthProvider] = [ FUIGoogleAuth() ]
        authUI?.providers = pp
        if let authVC = authUI?.authViewController() {
            present(authVC, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth,
      didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?,url: URL?, error: Error?) {
        let u = authDataResult?.user
        print("Successful login via authUI \(String(describing: u?.displayName))")
        continueWhenUserPresent()
    }

    private func continueWhenUserPresent() {
        .. pushViewController .. your first screen
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if the user is logged in or not:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
 // User is signed in.
 // ...
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
 // ...
}
```

if the user is logged in, then go the Home `ViewController`. This way when he opens the app again he will go to the Home `ViewController` unless he sign outs`FIRAuth.auth().signOut()`

For more info check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

Comment: so do I put that in my Login View controller, or AppDelegate or where?

Comment: create a view controller before the login view controller and put it there. It will be the first view controller when the app is opened. That way it will check in the beginning and will go to the right `ViewController`.

Answer (score 2):

For keep user login you need to check currentUser Auth session, If it's not nil then you can redirect user to Home screen.

Call "**setRootViewController**" method from **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, just after FirebaseApp.configure() code

**Swift 4**

```
    func setRootViewController() {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            // Set Your home view controller Here as root View Controller
            self.presentTabBar()
        } else {
            // Set you login view controller here as root view controller
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement this(Sorry about the delay). My FirebaseApp.configure() is in my AppDelegate. However when I try to declare my presentTabBar() function, I get an error saying AppDelegate has no memeber present. I think this is because AppDelegate isn't a viewController. Can I implement this in another way/ViewController?